# how to validate controls using jquery?

Tags: jquery, validation

i develouped one application. i write the client code using jquery.now i wnat to do the validations for my html controls.pls help me how to validate controls  using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple common jquery validation.

http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jquery/form_validation/

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [jquery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). And here's a [tutorial](http://corpocrat.com/2009/07/15/quick-easy-form-validation-tutorial-with-jquery/) that will get you started quickly.